# Databricks REST API throttling and capacity restrictions/limits

Tags: apache-spark, databricks, azure-databricks

I've scaled up the hardware on an azure-databricks cluster ("all-purpose" cluster) appropriately so that it should handle a very large amount of work.  The application is designed in a way where incoming data is processed in smallish, discrete chunks.  The jobs run in ~20 to 30 seconds.  But there is a high degree of concurrent jobs that need to execute at the same time (eg. anywhere from 0 to 50 simultaneous jobs).

The only approach for delivering jobs to the cluster seems to be by way of their REST API in azure databricks (doc: https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/api/latest/jobs.html )

Everything behaves normally until the number of concurrent jobs reaches 10 or so.  At that point I see an unreasonable deterioration in throughput.  But if I check ganglia or custom telemetry, there appears to be no reason for the deteriorated performance.

My suspicion is that the REST API itself is introducing an artificial bottleneck and they are throttling the number of jobs I can send over to my cluster.  This was not self-evident to me.  If I am paying for a large cluster, I should be allowed to send jobs to it.  The REST API seems to be doing little more than serving as a communication channel that allows me to transmit my requests to my cluster.  That API is the last place I would expect to find a resource bottleneck.  A Spark developer would naturally investigate their code, then the cluster hardware.  The REST API is not a reasonable place for Databricks to be introducing some additional, secretive limitations.

Does anyone know of another way to transmit distinct jobs to a cluster without going thru the REST API?  Eg. is there a way for the driver node in the cluster to spawn additional/distinct/first-class jobs without being counted against our REST API allowance?

This issue seems silly and artificial.  The secretive nature of these limits is bothersome to me as well.  If they are throttling the REST API then there should be a warning, error, or ganglia chart for that.  Otherwise developers will struggle with the performance issues using trial and error and guesswork.

Any help is appreciated.  I'd prefer not to go all the way back to the drawing board, because of an artificial restriction in their REST API (one that was probably put in place to protect an underpowered "control plane").

Answer (score 0):

Spark is awesome, but it isn't designed to be a high-concurrency database. The folks at Databricks have done a lot to lift the concurrency limitations of Spark, it still isn't a high-concurrecy solution.

In other words, your problem isn't the REST API ... it's the Spark engine in Databricks.

I know you don't want to go back to the drawing board, but the choices here are all bad ones:

- you can run multiple Databricks clusters ( https://docs.databricks.com/clusters/index.html ) and use NGINX or some other load balancer to distribute the API requests. This will get expensive, quickly, but will avoid redesign.
- If your use case supports it, try using a real-time database that supports high concurrency. I like Druid (see https://druid.apache.io or https://imply.io if you want a managed version), but there are others in the same category

Comment: Spark is not a database.